# Laravel / PHP Manipulate Collection Records

Tags: php, object, laravel-4

I'm trying to manipulate an Eloquent object. Below is the structure of the object in Json for ease of reading. Each record is an answer to a question.  You'll notice that there are two instances (1 and 2) in the records.

Here are the objectives:

1) Get all the related "answer" fields into one record (grouped by "instance" -- which defines the relationship -- as discussed below)

2) Group the records by instance. I need all the records with "instance": "1" grouped together and all the records with "instance": "2" grouped together.

3) Maintain the items in a collection to be passed to the view

DESIRED FORMAT: (note how the records are grouped by "instance" and I can now loop through them, which is my objective here)

```
[
    {
       "1": "John",
       "2": "A",
       "3": "Livingston",
       "instance": "1"
    },
    {
       "1": "Jake",
       "2": "B",
       "3": "Miller"
       "instance": "2"
    }
]
```

RAW OUTPUT:

```
[
[
    {
        "id": 1241,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 46,
        "answer": "John",
        "instance": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1271,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 46,
        "answer": "Jake",
        "instance": "2"
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 1242,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 47,
        "answer": "A",
        "instance": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1272,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 47,
        "answer": "B",
        "instance": "2"
    }
],

[
    {
        "id": 1240,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 48,
        "answer": "Livingston",
        "instance": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1279,
        "project_id": 1080,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 48,
        "answer": "Miller",
        "instance": "2"
    }
],

]
```

Here's some code that got me close to the desired outcome but threw an offset error if the number of answers in each instance didn't match exactly:

```
        // the $answers object is the one I'm trying to manipulate. 
        // for context, $answers->toJson() gives the raw json output above
            foreach($answers as $answer)
            {
                $numOfAnswers = $answer->count();
            }


            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $numOfAnswers) {
                $resource{$i} = $answers->fetch($i);  
                $i++;
            }   

            // This returns 'John' on the first loop, 'Jake' on the second loop, etc.
            foreach($resource as $answerGroup)
            {
                 $answerGroup->fetch('answer')[1]
            }
```

Comment: Yes sir, will get to work on it right away... where is the code that you've tried?

Comment: SamV, thanks. I added some code I tried above.

Comment: How do you intend to get 3 identical properties `answer` in one object?

Comment: Cheelahim, that was a typo. It's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good style to combine keys and numeric indexes in one array... Anyway I was manipulating with multi-dimentional arrays, this is what I got:

```
  $answers = [];
  foreach ($initialCollection as $item) {
        foreach ($item as $answer) {
            $instance = $answer['instance'];
            if (!isset($answers[$instance])) {
                $answers[$instance] = [
                    'instance'  => $instance,
                    'answers'   => [$answer['answer']],
                ];
            } else {
                $answers[$instance]['answers'][] = $answer['answer'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Try this and check the result. You may want to make new collection from that.

Comment: Initially, I'm getting this error exception: "Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection has no effect" on this line: $answers[$instance]['answers'][] = $answer['answer'];  Still working on it.

Comment: `$answers` should be a simple array